# Completely upgrading to Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade

I am thinking of fully upgrading to Ubuntu. I already have it dual booted with Windows Vista and Ubuntu (only from a CD). If I were to completely upgrade to Ubuntu. Would there be any problems? Im paranoid of upgrading my OS so I just want to be sure.
EDIT: I want to be only Ubuntu. If I were to install it from the CD would vista be gone? I want only Ubuntu. I cannot dual boot on my laptop as there is  only one hard drive and I don't know how to partition.

Comment: If you were to remove the Windows Vista partition, Ubuntu would be not be affected. It would be the same as it is right now.

Comment: Welcome Williams! What I understood that u have windows and running Ubuntu from CD.Now you thinking to erase Windows and install Ubuntu as one and only OS.Right? If not,please edit your post.

Answer (score 2):

I have been playing with Ubuntu since V 7.04
I have been dual booting with Windows the entire time. There are a few times I went 100% ubuntu, and with my lack of expertise, lost tonnes of my data when I had problems with Ubuntu.

My recommendation is that you have 3 partitions, a Windows one, a Ubuntu one, and a media one. Keep all important files and media on your media partition which you will be able to access from either operating system (if you make Media NTFS both OS can read / write to it)

Long story short, don't get rid of Windows until you are very secure with Linux. Ubuntu provides by far the easiest Linux OS to use. But it's a risk to move over everything all at once. (From my experience any ways.)

Comment: I agree with Frantum.Best answer comes from experience.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's a couple of choices. First you can install it over Windows, secondly you can install it, but as a second OS with Windows (dual booting).

I would advise against the single boot in your case which would wipe out windows.

I would go for install as a dual boot system, should be ok.

Most of my pc's have windows and Ubuntu dual boots.  Windows is basically there when I get it anyway.

Make sure you save ALL files on cloud and hard (local) media before doing anything!!!

Whenever messing with OS's you are taking a chance (just see others horror stories here, so backup, backup, backup (and test the backups) and allow plenty of time and the possibility of some complete failures for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have lost my data quite a few times too but i would not at all ask you to change your thoughts of quiting windows..!!

Coz its Best...!! ;)

what you can do is create 2/3 partitions where you keep your media and one partition for Ubuntu...I do this myself after a year of Experience...

You can always recover through LIVE CD/USB if you have these partitions...

And also having a backup of the data in your ubuntu partition on UBUNTU ONE or other cloud services like DROPBOX is a great idea...The online(cloud) backup has helped me recently..!!!

So now i have my data from the ubuntu partition back too along withe thae data that  remained intact in the other partitions... :)

Hope to see you upgrade to complete Ubuntu..!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm going to recommend you create three partitions for Ubuntu: one for / (this should be about 20 GB), one for /home, and one swap (the swap partition should be the same size as your amount of RAM or larger). The reason I recommend this is if your operating system gets botched you can reinstall it without touching any of the info in your home folder. If you install the operating system on the same partition as your /home directory you'll have to format everything and risk losing your files.

It's hard to migrate from Windows to Ubuntu, but it sounds like you're ready. When you're ready to get rid of Windows and install Ubuntu just delete any partitions that are on the hard drive and create those three partitions I described above.

Before you make the switch make sure you're aware of all the different Linux alternative programs for the programs you're used to on Windows. Also make sure all your files are in formats that can be used in Ubuntu, and change formats if necessary.